# Visual Studio is not compiling due to lib error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, irrklang

i installed "Irrklang" sound library to include it in a project, but whenever i try to compile, i get errors like that

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       unexpected token '\b'       C:\Users\HRJunior\Documents\IRRklang\lib\Winx64-visualStudio\irrKlang.lib   4
```

i have about 800 of those in a single file (the irrklang.lib), any idea?

VS Enterprise 2019 / W10 1903

Comment: It seems you try to build the library file as a source file. You should not. Instead you should *link* with it. To explain a little more: When you build your project, the compiler will compile the source files into *object files*. Object file are binary files with generated machine code. These object files are then passed to a *linker* which links them together into the executable file. A static library (like the `.lib` file you try to use) is basically an archive of object files. I.e. the library is already compiled, and just needs to be linked.

Comment: You do not want to compile a binary files

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `.lib` file in the *project properties*, it looks like you might have tried to include it with `#include`.

If you look in the download, you should see a number of files and directories such as:

- `lib\Winx64-visualStudio\irrKlang.lib`
- `bin\winx64-visualStudio\` containing some examples and 3 DLL's
- `include\` containing a bunch of `.h` files.
- `examples\` containing a bunch of example projects include Visual Studio solutions.

So what we have here is a DLL library, with an import library (`.lib`) and a bunch of header files.

The example projects are a good thing to compare to and see where your project is wrong.

If you right click on your project -> properties -> Linker -> General. Under "Additional Library Directories" -> Edit add a line with the directory containing the `.kib` file, e.g. `C:\Users\HRJunior\Documents\IRRklang\lib\Winx64-visualStudio\` (at this point I would note that the project probably won't work if given to anyone else. You might put IRRklang in a subdirectory of your project, e.g. `C:\Users\HRJunior\Documents\CoolProject\thirdparty\IRRklang\lib\Winx64-visualStudio\` then in MSVC use `$(SolutionDir)thirdparty\IRRklang\lib\Winx64-visualStudio\`, then you can give anyone `C:\Users\HRJunior\Documents\CoolProject\` and it should work).

Then under Linker -> Input, for Additional Dependencies -> Edit add a line with `irrKlang.lib`. Alternatively add the line `#pragma comment(lib, "irrKlang.lib")` somewhere in your source.

Then under C/C++ -> General, for Additional Include Directories -> Edit add a line to the directory containing the headers, `C:\Users\HRJunior\Documents\IRRklang\include`.

At this point your project should build, but trying to run you will get a missing DLL error, copy those 3 DLL files to your output directory containing your exe. You could have VS do this automatically by in properties going Build Events -> Post Build Event then for Command Line using a copy command such as: `xcopy "C:\Users\HRJunior\Documents\IRRklang\bin\winx64-visualStudio\*.dll" "$(OutDir)" /Y`